# Passing entry box from classA to a label in class B tkinter Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Hello everyone im new to tkinter and ive tried all of the examples for passing value from one class to another class in tkinter but doesnt seem to work. I want the entry box in my login page to display as a label in my home page. Would really appreaciate any help received!!

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        MyFrontend.configure(self, background="lightblue")

        logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
        tk.Label(self, image=logo).pack()


        labelNric = tk.Label(self, text="NRIC:", font=LARGE_FONT_NOBOLD, background="lightblue", foreground="darkslategray")
        labelNric.place(x=80,y=220)

        # entry box for user input
        entryNric = tk.Entry(self, highlightbackground="lightblue")
        # entryNric.bind("<Return>", getNric)
        entryNric.place(x=280,y=223)

        labelEgnric = tk.Label(self, text="E.g. SXXXX123A", font=SMALL_FONT, background="lightblue", foreground="darkslategray")
        labelEgnric.place(x=285,y=253)

        def error_popupmsg(msg):

            popup = tk.Tk()

            popup.wm_title("Error")

            popup.geometry("400x200")

            popup.configure(background="darkred")

            labelError = tk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=MED_FONT, background="darkred", foreground="white")
            labelError.place(x=140, y=60)

            buttonOk = tk.Button(popup, text="Got it!", highlightbackground ="#8B0000", command=popup.destroy)
            buttonOk.place(x=170, y=100)

            popup.mainloop()

        def checkNric(arg=None):
            nric_check = entryNric.get()
            if nric_check == 'S1234567B' or nric_check == 'S1234567C':
                controller.show_frame(HomePage)
            else:
                error_popupmsg("Invalid NRIC!")

        buttonSubmit = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: checkNric())
        buttonSubmit.place(x=380,y=290)


class HomePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        MyFrontend.configure(self, background="lightblue")

        labelNricInfo = tk.Label(self, text="Patient's NRIC/FIN:", font=SMALL_FONT, background="lightblue", foreground="darkslategray")
        labelNricInfo.place(x=50,y=40)

        # to display NRIC from entry box in login page here
        labelNricDisplay = tk.Label(self, text="", font=SMALL_FONT, foreground="darkslategray")
        labelNricDisplay.place(x=170,y=40)

        buttonBack = ttk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
        buttonBack.place(x=370,y=420)

        buttonSubmit = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit")

        buttonSubmit.place(x=460,y=420)
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit too vague. What does that mean? Does the wrong thing appear? Nothing appear? Right thing appear in the wrong place? An error is thrown? ...?

Comment: You can declare a global `StringVar` and associate it to the `Label` and `Entry` widgets using `textvariable` option.

Comment: I did try using the StringVar method but it returns me a null. I also tried declaring global variable for the nric value but it will always return me back a value that i initially declared globally. Meaning to say that it is not overriding my value with the new value entered in the entry field. Any idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable for your class `LoginPage`, and make your entry as an attribute of the class.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.entryNric = tk.Entry(self, highlightbackground="lightblue")
        self.entryNric.pack()
        self.entryNric.insert(0,"Hi i am an entry")
        self.pack()

login = LoginPage(root)
print (login.entryNric.get()) #access the class attribute
root.mainloop()
```